# Backand/Ionic - How to retrieve data of logged in user?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, backand

I am using Backand as my database and they provided a todo app on their github but it only retrieve all the data of the users. I only want to retrieve the data of the logged in user. How can I do this?

Somewhat, I want to modify it on my services.js:

```
    service.all = function () {
        return $http.get(getUrl());
    };
```

I want to pass the object of the current user.

GitHub: https://github.com/backand/todos-with-users

Comment: use any user ID to get information of particular user.

Comment: @AnujGupta the problem is the user has multiple todos.

Comment: You should use the Security Tab as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38100830/3809559

Answer (score 0):

There is a todo with users demo. https://github.com/backand/angular-yeoman-todos/tree/todo-with-users

Ultimately, my user service looks something like this...

```
angular.module('app.services')

.service('userService', ['Backand', '$state', '$q', '$http', 'authService', function(Backand, $state, $q, $http, authService) {
this.getUserByEmail = function(email) {

    var resultsDeferred = $q.defer();
    var requestDeferred = $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: Backand.getApiUrl() + '/1/objects/users',
        params: {
            pageSize: 1,
            pageNumber: 1,
            filter: [{
                fieldName: 'email',
                operator: 'equals',
                value: email
            }],
            sort: ''
        }
    });

    requestDeferred.then(function(response) {
        var user = response.data.data;
        resultsDeferred.resolve(user); // allow the controller to render
    }, function failureCallback(reason) {
        resultsDeferred.reject(reason); // bubble up failure
    });
    return resultsDeferred;
}
```

}]);

You get the email from ...

```
var user = Backand.getUserDetails();
var userEmail = null;

if (user.$$state.value !== null) {
    userEmail = user.$$state.value.username;
} else {
    userEmail = null;
}

var userDeferred = userService.getUserByEmail($scope.userEmail).promise;

        userDeferred.then(function successCallback(response) {
            $scope.user = response[0];
            console.log('userId (email): %o', $scope.user.id);
            console.log('user phone: %o', $scope.user.phone);
        });
```